# Non-Authoritative Sites in Enterprise Search

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

I have two content sources.

The first is the SharePoint site itself, with around 400 items in its index on my test environment.

The second is a public facing website (external, non SharePoint) which we've indexed. This contains around 8000 items.

We want a search on the All Sites scope to return the SharePoint site results first, then the external, public site results at the end.

I've added the url to the SharePoint web app to the Most Authoritative Pages box (and even tried this without) - and added the external site to Non-Authoritative Sites.

However, the search results still appear completely mixed up together, with both the public and internal sites' results appearing randomly, using whatever ranking Enterprise Search Uses.

How can I enforce sites listed in the Non-Authoritative Sites to appear at the end of Search Results (Core Results Web Part)?

Comment: Can't you edit the XSLT of the core results web part to use your own sort order?  You could do substring matching on the item URL and sort on that?

Comment: That might be a last resort, if it would work. Being as some queries can bring back around 800 results, I'd have to see how quick XPath can work across a result set of that size. Also, this might knacker any other ranking that's in effect. Cheers though!

Comment: Tweaking those will alter the relevancy, but the external content maybe better and percolate up in the results even though you're trying to suppress it.

Comment: Are you using FAST or SharePoint Search?

Comment: @Daniel: Enterprise Search, not FAST.

Comment: @Eric: According to this doc: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262796.aspx then apparently 'non-authoritative sites' always rank lower than everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I resolved it.

First I wondered if it was the number of items in my test site, so I added 1200 other items.

Next I added another web app to the Most Authoritative pages, along side the main web app I'm wanting to surface to the top of the results, and kept the external site at non-authoritative.

Then I reset the index and Fully Crawled both sources. Seems to be fine now.